# CSS- make a list inside a div

Tags: html, css

I'd like to know how to insert text just inside a div automatically. I use `<br>` for it , but is it the best way?

here is my code :

**HTML**

```
    <div class="resume">
        <div class="resume_class">
            <ul>
            <h3>Skills</h3>
                <li>Languages: C++, Java , C , HTML , PHP</li>
                <li>Frameworks: .NET, Zendesk , Solid<br> works NetBeans Rational Rose, SPSS, Maple</li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.resume
{   
    margin-right: 2%;
}
.resume_class
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 27%;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    background: purple;
}
.resume_class ul
{
    position: absolute;
}
```

```css
.resume {
  margin-right: 2%;
}
.resume_class {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 27%;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  background: purple;
}
.resume_class ul {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="resume">
  <div class="resume_class">
    <ul>
      <h3>Skills</h3>
      <li>Languages: C++, Java , C , HTML , PHP</li>
      <li>Frameworks: .NET, Zendesk , Solid
        <br>works NetBeans Rational Rose, SPSS, Maple</li>

    </ul>
  </div>
```

**EDITED:** I want change this :

[image]

to something like

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by _insert text just inside a div automatically_ ?

Comment: Insert text and `<br>`? I am a bit lost. Can you reword to explain it better?

Comment: in `resume_class` styles, you have set `width` to 27%. That is why it looks like this. Make it 100%.

Comment: @tibzon I want three of this class in a row.

Comment: Do you really need the `position: absolute` for the `ul`? `<br>` is certainly not the best way to achieve this. Try having a look at `word-wrap`.

Comment: just use `.resume_class { position: relative; }`

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have direct child elements in a `ul` other than `li`. Apart from that, your main problem is your absolute positioning. This takes the element out of the flow of elements, so that the surrounding container fully ignores it. You need no linebreaks  without absolute positioning. If it has to be `position: absolute;`, give the `ul` the width you want.

Comment: @RishavKundu just answer the question or take a properly comment.

Comment: @afn what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `.resume_class { position: relative; }`

```css
.resume {
  margin-right: 2%;
}
.resume_class {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 27%;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  background: purple;
  position: relative;
}
.resume_class ul {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="resume">
  <div class="resume_class">
    <ul>
      <h3>Skills</h3>
      <li>Languages: C++, Java , C , HTML , PHP</li>
      <li>Frameworks: .NET, Zendesk , Solid
        <br>works NetBeans Rational Rose, SPSS, Maple</li>

    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `position: absolute` on your ul. If you have to, you have to use `position: relative` or `position: absolute` on your div.

Answer (score 1):

Try this  change  .resume_class css position

```css
.resume
{   
    margin-right: 2%;
}
.resume_class
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 27%;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    background: purple;
   position: relative;
}
.resume_class ul
{
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="resume">
        <div class="resume_class">
            <ul>
            <h3>Skills</h3>
                <li>Languages: C++, Java , C , HTML , PHP</li>
                <li>Frameworks: .NET, Zendesk , Solid<br> works NetBeans Rational Rose, SPSS, Maple</li>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
.resume
{   
    margin-right: 2%;
}
.resume_class
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 27%;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    background: purple;
   position: relative;
}
.resume_class ul
{
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="resume">
        <div class="resume_class">
            <ul style="width:100%">
            <h3>Skills</h3>
                <li>Languages: C++, Java , C , HTML , PHP</li>
                <li>Frameworks: .NET, Zendesk , Solid works NetBeans Rational Rose, SPSS, Maple</li>

            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: don't copy from another answer.